# How to populate large integer arrays in Solidity?

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm currently building an NFT fantasy league game on ethereum where I want to add the functionality of on demand minting of random tokens. For that I need to keep track of the tokens that are available for minting so that I can choose random ones from them. The only strategy I could find was to store the token Ids for a player in an array, and pop the id after minting. This eliminates any chance of collisions since the token now doesn't exist in the array anymore and if I land on the same index, a new Id is there.

But the problem is I can't find any way of populating an array so big (in my case 40000 integers from 1-40000). It runs out of gas if I use a for loop and populate it in the smart contract or even if I pass the entire array from javascript as an argument in a function.

Is there any way to populate arrays of this size other than doing it in batches using multiple transactions (it allows me to send an array 1000 integers to the contract but that leads to way to many transactions when I have hundreds of players each having 40 thousand tokens). Also if there's a different way to accomplish this task other than using arrays I'd be open to that too.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract test {

mapping(uint16=>uint16[]) public availableTokens;
//Player=>tokens mapping

function pushNumbers(uint16 player) public {
        uint16 i = 0; //tokens
        
        for (i=0; i<40000; i++){
          availableTokens[player].push(i);
        }
        
    }
//Runs out of gas

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your question, I have a better solution

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
contract Test {
    mapping(uint16 => bool) public usedTokens;  
    uint16 public totalTokens = 40000;  
    
    function getRandomToken(uint16 player) public returns (uint16) {
        require(player > 0, "Invalid player ID");  
        
        uint16 tokenId = _generateRandomToken(player);  //
        while (usedTokens[tokenId]) {  
            tokenId = _generateRandomToken(player);
        }
        
        usedTokens[tokenId] = true;  
        return tokenId;  
    }
    
    function _generateRandomToken(uint16 player) private view returns (uint16) {
        uint16 randomNumber = uint16(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, player))));
        return (randomNumber % totalTokens) + 1;  
    }
}
```

In this method, we do not pre fill the array, but instead use the call getRandomToken() to generate random tokens for specific players as needed

I don't know if I understand correctly, but I hope it can be helpful to you

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time for this. But the problem with this is that in the worst case scenario it will be very difficult to land on the available tokens. For example if 39999 tokens are minted and one is left it will be near impossible to get it. Plus I'll be using chainlink vrf for generating random number and I can't call that so many times. That's the problem arrays solve. You only have the remaining ones left in them and you can use the array length as the the max range for the random number to land on an index.

Comment: Perhaps you can only execute in batches, as long as the maximum limit of gas is not exceeded